# Electronic drum noise in flats/apartments (travelling upwards!)

Tags: drums

I've been drumming for a number years now and I've only just invested in an electronic drum kit for practise purposes. I specifically bought a Roland TD-25kv because it has a great brain and most importantly: decent noise "conscious" pads.

I've read many, many articles across the internet which speak of people (understandably) having trouble in first floor apartments and above where the bass drum and Hi-Hat foot noise and vibrations travel downwards. I am having the opposite issue.

All of the drum pads (except the cymbals which are rubber) are a mesh material and the KD-9 bass drum trigger is a cloth-like material. I have to use the plastic side of the beater to avoid the drum pad being eaten away by the felt side of the beater.

I live in a ground floor apartment surrounded by solid concrete walls. The drum kit itself is in the corner of the living room on thick carpet. Buying/making a tennis ball riser may not fix the issue because I don't think the vibrations are an issue, it's the noise of the beater on the pad.

After my rambling, does anyone know of a way to reduce this noise and how to deal with a very angry neighbour?

Thanks for your help!
Jack

Comment: Can you get a little more explicit about what's happening with the noise? You have complaints from neighbors above you while playing mesh V-drums? Are you wearing headphones coming from the brain or using an amp?

Comment: Check the link to the possible duplicate. According to one answer, even if you're on the ground floor the vibrations can be transmitted up the walls to an apartment above, so a riser can still help. Also note that the possible duplicate has a link to another V-drum question that has more tips.